# Javascript, Only send email when form validates correctly

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, mailto

I have two separate buttons on an html form which validate the inputs and then send the form respectively. I want to merge these buttons together so that the email will generate only when the form is validated correctly. I've included my code below and any solutions or ideas would be greatly appreciated:

```js
// JavaScript Document

function ValidateForm() {
 //Sets variables for testing the inputs by obtaining the values entered into the field
 var firstName = document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value;
 var lastName = document.getElementById('txtLastName').value;
 var DOB = document.getElementById('txtDob').value;
 var pattern =/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;
 //This pattern acts as a template for the DOB field to follow
 var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail').value;
 var atpos = email.indexOf('@');
 var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf('.');
 //These variables check for the placement of the @ and . inside the email input
 var feedback = document.getElementById('txtFeedback').value;
 var invalidForm = 0; 

 if (firstName == "") {
  document.getElementById('txtFirstName').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errFirstName').innerHTML = "Must Enter a Valid First Name"; 
  invalidForm=1;
 }
 else if (firstName.length >15) {
  document.getElementById('txtFirstName').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errFirstName').innerHTML = "Must be Less than 15 Characters";
  invalidForm=1; 
 }
 else if (isNaN(firstName) == false){ //checks whether the input is a umber or not
  document.getElementById('txtFirstName').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errFirstName').innerHTML = "Letters only Please";
  invalidForm=1;
 }
 else if (firstName.length <3) {
  document.getElementById('txtFirstName').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errFirstName').innerHTML = "Must be More than 3 Characters";
  invalidForm=1; 
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById('txtFirstName').className = "defaultStyle";
  document.getElementById('errFirstName').innerHTML = ""; 
 }
 
 if (lastName == "") {
  document.getElementById('txtLastName').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errLastName').innerHTML = "Must Enter a Valid Surname"; 
  invalidForm=1; 
 } 
 else if (lastName.length >15) {
  document.getElementById('txtLastName').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errLastName').innerHTML = "Must be Less than 15 Characters"; 
  invalidForm=1; 
 } 
 else if (isNaN(lastName) == false){
  document.getElementById('txtFirstName').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errFirstName').innerHTML = "Letters only Please";
  invalidForm=1;
 }
 else if (lastName.length <3) {
  document.getElementById('txtLastName').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errLastName').innerHTML = "Must be More than 3 Characters";
  invalidForm=1; 
 } 
 else {
  document.getElementById('txtLastName').className = "defaultStyle";
  document.getElementById('errLastName').innerHTML = ""; 
 }
 
 if (DOB == null || DOB == "" || !pattern.test(DOB)) { 
 //tests whether DOB field is empty, blank, or doesn't fir the template set as seen above in the variables
  document.getElementById('txtDob').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errDob').innerHTML = "Must Enter a valid Date of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY)";
  invalidForm=1;
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById('txtDob').className = "defaultStyle";
  document.getElementById('errDob').innerHTML =""; 
 }
 
 if (email =="") {
  document.getElementById('txtEmail').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errEmail').innerHTML = "Must Enter an Email";
  invalidForm=1; 
 }
 else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos || dotpos+2 == email.length) {
  document.getElementById('txtEmail').className ="errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errEmail').innerHTML ="Must Enter a Valid Email";
  invalidForm=1;
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById('txtEmail').className ="defaultStyle";
  document.getElementById('errEmail').innerHTML = "";
 }
 
 if (feedback == "") {
  document.getElementById('txtFeedback').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errFeedback').innerHTML = "Must Enter Some Feedback"; 
  invalidForm=1; 
 }
 else if (feedback.length > 1000) {
  document.getElementById('txtFeedback').className = "errorStyle";
  document.getElementById('errFeedback').innerHTML = "Must Enter Some Feedback that does not exceed 200 characters"; 
  invalidForm=1;
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById('txtFeedback').className ="defaultStyle";
  document.getElementById('errFeedback').innerHTML = "";
 }
  
 if  (invalidForm ==0) {
  alert("Your Information that has been entered is valid and ready to send, simply click the Submit button to do so.");
 }
 
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="MAILTO:dcrummey@belfastmet.ac.uk; pauldocherty@belfastmet.ac.uk?Subject=Belfast%20Met%20Sights%20and%20Sounds%20Feedback" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
             <fieldset style="width:85%; margin:auto;">
                <legend>Your Details</legend>
                <img src="../Images/Submit-Query.gif" width="30%" alt="Submit Your Images" style="display:block; float:right; padding-right:20px;"/>
              <p class="myText">Title:       
                      <select name="Title " id="txtTitle"> 
                        <option value=" Mr">Mr</option> 
                        <option value=" Mrs">Mrs</option> 
                        <option value=" Ms">Ms</option> 
                        <option value=" Miss">Miss</option> 
                        <option value=" Dr">Dr</option> 
                        <option value=" Prof">Prof</option> 
                    </select> 
                    <span class="errSpan" id="errTitle"></span>
                    </p>
                    
           <p class="myText">First Name: 
                    <input name="First Name " type="text" id="txtFirstName" />  
                    <span class="errSpan" id="errFirstName"></span>
                    </p>
              
            <p class="myText">Last Name: 
                    <input name="Last Name " type="text" id="txtLastName" />  
                    <span class="errSpan" id="errLastName"></span>
                    </p>
           
                  <p class="myText">Gender: 
                    <select name="Gender " id="txtGender"> 
                        <option value=" Male">Male</option> 
                        <option value=" Female">Female</option> 
                    </select>
                    </p>
                 
            <p class="myText">DOB: 
                    <input name="DOB "type="text" id="txtDob" /> 
                    <span class="errSpan" id="errDob"></span> 
                    </p>
            
            <p class="myText">Email Address: 
                    <input name="Email Address " type="text" id="txtEmail" /> 
                    <span class="errSpan" id="errEmail"></span>
                    </p> 
                </fieldset>
                 <br />
              <fieldset style="width:85%; margin:auto;">
                <legend class="text">Your Feedback</legend>
                 <p class="myText">Feedback Type: 
                    <select name="Feedback Type " id="txtFeedbackType"> 
                        <option value=" General Feedback">General Feedback</option> 
                        <option value=" Query">Query</option> 
                        <option value=" Suggestion">Suggestion</option> 
                        <option value=" Other(Please Specify Below)">Other (Please Specify Below)</option> 
                    </select> 
                    <span class="errSpan" id="errFeedbackType"></span>
                    </p>
                  
                  <p class="myText">Feedback: 
                  <textarea class="myText" name="Feedback" cols="30" rows="5" id="txtFeedback"></textarea> 
                  <span class="errSpan" id="errFeedback"></span>
                  </p>
              </fieldset>
                 <br />    
                <input onclick="ValidateForm();" type="button" value="Check Information" /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Send Feedback" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset Fields"/>
                
   </form>
```

Comment: disable the mail sending button. If the form is valid then only enable it

Comment: And be sure to validate on the backend as well. Javascript validation is easy to bypass

Answer (score 0):

Use the form's `onsumbit` event. Return `true` if validated ok, else `false`:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" ....
```

And then change the function to:

```
if  (invalidForm ==0) {
    alert("Your Information that has been entered is valid and ready to send.");
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Here is a very simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/83LLcq3u/1/

Comment: i love you, thanks, you're the best, worked perfectly